# How to sum (totalize) a variable in grid using for each?

Tags: genexus

UI'm new in genexus and I'm trying to make a simple sales system.
I'm trying to totalize a variable using a `For Each line in Grid`

Here's my screen:

SaleScreen

[image: 1]

My SubTotal works but Total stay one step behind

And here's my code:

```
Event GridProduct.Load
 For Each Product
  &ProductPicture= ProductPicture
  &ProductPrice = ProductPrice
  GridProduct.Load()
 EndFor
Endevent

Event 'BtnPlus'
 &ProductQty= &ProductQty + 1
 Do 'SubTotal'
 Do 'Total'
EndEvent

Event 'BtnMinus'
 &ProductQty= &ProductQty - 1
 Do 'SubTotal'
 Do 'Total'
EndEvent

Event 'SubTotal'
 &ProductSubTotal = &ProductPrice * &ProductQty
 GridProduct.Load()
EndEvent

Event 'Total'
 &ProductTotal = 0
 For Each line in GridProduct
  &ProductTotal = &ProductTotal + &ProductSubTotal 
 EndFor 
 GridProduct.Load()
EndEvent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem using 2 situations:
To totalize when use button `+` and `-`:

```
Event 'BtnPlus'
 &ProductQty = &ProductQty + 1
 &ProductTotal = &ProductTotal - &ProductPrice 
 GridProduct.Load()
EndEvent

Event 'BtnLess'
 &ProductQty = &ProductQty - 1
 &ProductTotal = &ProductTotal - &ProductPrice 
 GridProduct.Load()
EndEvent
```

And when the cliente type in `&ProductQty`

```
Event &ProductQty.ControlValueChanging(&ProductQtyValue)
    do 'SubTotal'
    do 'Total'
EndEvent

Sub 'SubTotal'
 &ProductSubTotal = &ProductPrice * &ProductQty
EndSub

Sub 'Total'
 &ProductTotal = 0
 For Each line in GridProduct
  &ProductTotal = &ProductTotal + &ProductSubTotal 
 EndFor 
EndSub
```

Answer (score -1):

The *[Do](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8581,Do%20command)* command only works with subroutines, not with **Events**. So '*SubTotal*' and '*Total*' should be subroutines instead of [Events](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8044,User%20defined%20event).

Comment: Thanks Alejandro Cynowicz i had already tried this suggestion but i think my mistake was to be using 2 types of totalization. Using `+` and `-` buttons and `&ProductQty.ControlValueChanging`. I had to separate, when i type in `&ProductQty` i use `Sub 'Total'` and when i use buttons i have to totalize on `Event 'BtnPlus'`